# Spring boot icw legacy spring application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This is more of a spring architectural question and not a coding issue. To me it seems that some Spring Boot functionality is only available to Spring Boot making it effectively another framework on top of the Spring Framework. While it is possible to use some of those Spring Boot specific features in vanilla Spring, it seems that there is not always a clear guide on howto do this (in those cases it feels more like hacking).

So, when having a vanilla Spring application that requires some functionality only available in Spring Boot, is the advised way to migrate from vanilla Spring to Spring Boot? Or did they really intended it to make the Spring boot functionality also available to the Spring framework as well and is the hacking that is sometimes required by-design?

Comment: Spring Boot is an opinionated view of the Spring framework. There is nothing stopping you implementing what Spring boot does in Vanilla spring, but that comes at a cost of you are effectively duplicating effort. Everything that it does is built on Spring Framework. Its your choice if you want to take on that effort or just bite the bullet and move to spring boot.

Comment: Everything that Spring Boot does is ultimatly build on top of Spring. So stuff that is in there can be used without utilizing full Spring Boot. However getting it to run will probably require some manual configuration and trial-and-error to get right. It is probably easier to introduce Spring Boot itself into your legacy application.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, Spring Boot is a way of writing applications using one or more of the Spring libraries (Spring Core, Spring Security, ...) and simplifying the usage and configuration of the other libraries or as you said "another framework on top of the Spring Framework".
So, in the case of requiring some functionality from Spring Boot, the intended way is to use Spring Boot. As porting it to another application will heavily depend on the application, this will only be of very limited use to the Spring Boot project and community, so you have to do it on your own.
You're right, there seems to be no official guideline concerning only using parts of Spring Boot in your application, but I suppose that is not an intended usage. The Spring team did that with the Spring framework (now aka as Spring Core), where you could just use the dependency injection mechanism and could then add the parts you needed. I can imagine that questions from developers about how to best integrate or implement a Spring application has lead to the development of Spring Boot with a different approach: You start with a Spring Boot application and then customize and configure it.

Comment: For a new application this makes sense indeed: if you need something from Spring Boot, just start with Spring Boot. The vanilla Spring Framework can be fully leveraged through Spring Boot. The question is more if a (let's call it legacy) vanilla Spring application requires functionality from Spring Boot. There seems to be no "official" guideline if starting to use parts of Spring Boot from vanilla Spring is intended or not. Or that it's more future proof to just migrate the application doing it the Spring Boot way